# firefox Add-on SDK cfx tool open url parameter

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating firefox extension by using Add-on SDK, I am using [cfx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#cfx_run) tool to test and run add-on.

When I try to run tool from command line like;

```
cfx run '-url "www.google.com"'
```

it does open firefox but not navigating to google.com. Just opens blank page and obviously it does not run my extension. I need to navigate manually to a url to trigger my javascript-based extension.

Is there any way to call cfx tool to open a specific url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--binary-args=CMDARGS`

> additional arguments passed to the binary (run, test)

(See `cfx run --help` for additional arguments to `cfx run`)

E.g. the following works for me:

```
cfx run --binary-args="-url www.google.com"
```

Comment: helps great! thanks for quick answer. Just a quick-follow up question; is it logical way to test extension every time I change something? For example, for chrome extension, I just need to refresh extensions page and done. But firefox; forcing me to go console, run the cfx evertime and check the page which comes to me a little cumbersome.

Comment: That is not a "quick-follow up question", IMO, but one that deserves it's own real question, if there isn't one already.

Comment: Uh, alright.. I am seeking around and documentation and could not find something makes it 'more automatic'. If cannot find, sure will open a new thread for it.